# udev rules don't set group and permissions correctly

Tags: centos, udev, ttyusb

I'm trying to set `udev` rules to create a symlink for a USB device (ZWAVE stick), in a CentOS 7 machine.
It correctly sets the symlink, but with wrong group and permissions.

I've tried various values, in order to debug:

```
# cat 99-usb-serial.rules 
# Copied from https://github.com/openhab/openhab/wiki/symlinks
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{product}=="RFXrec433", SYMLINK+="USBrfxcom", GROUP="dialout", MODE="0666" 
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0658", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0200", SYMLINK+="USBzwave", GROUP="dialout", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0658", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0200", SYMLINK+="USBzwave1", GROUP="zvika", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0658", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0200", SYMLINK+="USBzwave2", GROUP="zvika"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0658", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0200", SYMLINK+="USBzwave3"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0658", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0200", SYMLINK+="USBzwave4", MODE="0700"
```

But all seem identical:

```
# ll /dev/USBzwave*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Nov  7 17:47 /dev/USBzwave -> ttyACM0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Nov  7 17:47 /dev/USBzwave1 -> ttyACM0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Nov  7 17:47 /dev/USBzwave2 -> ttyACM0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Nov  7 17:47 /dev/USBzwave3 -> ttyACM0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Nov  7 17:47 /dev/USBzwave4 -> ttyACM0
```

What's going on?
How to debug it?

I have tried running `udevadm control --log-priority=debug`.
But still there is no helpful information in `dmesg`, `/var/log/messages` or `udevadm monitor`

## EDIT

Now I understand that the `GROUP` and `MODE` actions changed the ttyACM0 definitions, and not the soft link...

Therefore, only the last rule is relevant - it overrides the previous rules.
Running `ll /dev/ttyACM0` gives the correct ownership and permission - for `ttyACM0`.

But why the `/dev/USBzwave` has different owenership and permission?